# How to use multiple group_concat with count,order by and group by in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, concatenation

I have a table t1

```
id  |   Date      | name
1   | 22-06-2017  | a
2   | 22-06-2017  | a
3   | 22-06-2017  | a
4   | 22-06-2017  | b
5   | 21-06-2017  | a
6   | 20-06-2017  | b
7   | 20-06-2017  | b
8   | 19-06-2017  | a
9   | 19-06-2017  | b
10  | 18-06-2017  | a
```

> I want a result of last 10 days from current date(22-06-2017) with each name and get the count of all ten day in single row. if there is no date present so it will show 0 count and they should be like 10th day in 1st place, 9th day in 2nd place and so on in row

```
count                |  name
0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,3  | a
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,1  | b
```

> can somebody please help me to write this query. its very helpful for me

Comment: "get the count of all ten day in single row" I can think of no sensible reason why you would want this.

Comment: i want to show this data on graph with multiple names in it. I have tried query but not get any proper solution.

Comment: MySQL has no (or only very crude) graphing capabilities. Handle issues of data display in application code.